# Trying to read a data base 4 file and getting an error

Tags: sql, vb.net, dbf

I'm trying to read 5 DBF files, MINFODIV.DBF, MINFO.DBF, MODE.DBF, DIVISION.DBF, MENU.DBF using SQL statements. No problems reading each individually into a table using VB.Net. I created the following SQL statement using Flyspeed SQL Query on the files and it works.

In VB.net I get

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
>
> 'midb1.AMOUNT
>
> From MINFODIV.DBF midb1
>
> Inner Join MINFO.DBF midb On midb1.MINFOID = midb.MINFOID
>
> Inner Join MODE.DBF modb On midb.MODEID = modb.MODEID
>
> Inner Join MENU.DBF medb On modb.MENUID = medb.MENUID
>
> Inner Join DIVISION.DBF didb On didb.DIVISIONID = midb1.DIVISIONID'"

My select statement is as follows:

```
Select 
  modb.DESC, 
  medb.DESC As DESC1, 
  didb.DESC As DESC2, 
  midb1.AMOUNT 
From 
  MINFODIV.DBF midb1 
  Inner Join MINFO.DBF midb On midb1.MINFOID = midb.MINFOID 
  Inner Join MODE.DBF modb On midb.MODEID = modb.MODEID 
  Inner Join MENU.DBF medb On modb.MENUID = medb.MENUID 
  Inner Join DIVISION.DBF didb On didb.DIVISIONID = midb1.DIVISIONID
```

Comment: in that first one are you not missing the word select?  like select midb1.Amount?

Comment: The first statement is the error returned from VB.net. I am passing the complete SQL statement listed below to the search.

Comment: @KevinBeckner I agree with the first comment, check the error message again (I formatted into a block quote for you). It is missing the first part of your query: `Select 
  modb.DESC, 
  medb.DESC As DESC1, 
  didb.DESC As DESC2,`. Can you make sure the entire query is passed?

Comment: Yes the "Select" statement and remaining statement parameters are passed to SqlString in the getdatabasetable Function.

Comment: OpendBConnection() Dim SelectCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select MENU.DESC As REV, MODE.DESC As MODE, DIVISION.DESC As DIV, MINFODIV.AMOUNT From MENU.DBF Inner Join MODE.DBF On MODE.MENUID = MENU.MENUID Inner Join MINFO.DBF On MINFO.MODEID = MODE.MODEID Inner Join MINFODIV.DBF On MINFODIV.MINFOID = MINFO.MINFOID Inner Join DIVISION.DBF On DIVISION.DIVISIONID = MINFODIV.DIVISIONID;", dBaseConnection)
Dim TableAdapter As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter TableAdapter.SelectCommand = SelectCommand
TableAdapter.Fill(tb) = Error

Comment: @KevinBeckner But is your error message really what you pasted in your question?

Comment: Yes, I bypassed my function and added the SQL query statement directly into the System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand see above. Still getting the same result.

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with maybe accessing too many DBF, I can perform a query with 2 DBF's with inner join but these 5 are not working. Seems to bomb after the first Inner Join